# Select second element with same class name in testing automation using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, unit-testing, puppeteer

I've structure like this

```
<div class='class1'>
   <div></div>
</div>
<div class="class1>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

I'm using this command to select the first element, but not able to figure out how to select second div with same class name or nth div with same class name.

```
div[class*="class1"]>div -> do some action
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to select all?

```
document.querySelectorAll(".class1")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [`nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) css selector: `div[class*="class1"]:nth-child(2)`